# SQL query returning the results, omitting the max value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have tables "Files" in which files are stored along with their versions, I need to extract from the table all the names of files, in addition to the files with the latest version.

```
    Name_File             Version
     file_1               1.2
     file_1               1.3
     file_1               1,4
     file_1               2.0
     file_2               1.1
     file_2               1.3      
     file_2               1.6
     file_2               2.0
     file_3               2.4
     file_3               2.5
     file_3               3.0
     etc...
```

Expected resulat:

```
    Name_File             Version
     file_1               1.2
     file_1               1.3
     file_1               1,4        
     file_2               1.1
     file_2               1.3      
     file_2               1.6         
     file_3               2.4
     file_3               2.5
```

Please help

Comment: Why do you have multiple results if you only want the latest version?  Where is `file_1`/`2.0`?

Comment: The criteria for your "expected result" is not clear at all.

Comment: I think the `in addition to the files with the latest version` is incorrect phrasing. It looks like OP wants all files except the highest `version` of each.

Comment: What's the data type of the column "version"? NUMERIC, VARCHAR?

Comment: Please add your current query and table scheme. The `phpmyadmin` and PHP tags can be removed. PHP isn't related, nor is the interface... unless you are trying to achieve this in PHP and not SQL, if so please add PHP as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Files t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT t3.Name_File, MAX(t3.Version) AS Version FROM Files t3 GROUP BY t3.Name_File) t2
 ON (t1.Name_File = t2.Name_File AND t1.Version < t2.Version)
WHERE t2.Version IS NOT NULL
```

Working [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70b844/1)

Comment: I'm not sure, but my intuition tells me it might be faster with `t1.Version = t2.Version WHERE t2.Version IS NULL` instead. Also, if there are complications calculating "max" `Version` due to field type, there could be complications with `<` that will not be an issue with `=`.